# How to use gas?

Tags: jagged-alliance-2

I'm playing on the jagged alliance 2 [1.13 fanpatch/mod](http://ja2v113.pbworks.com/w/page/4218339/FrontPage). (But that should not matter in this case). And I have an

> Ice Cream Van (yep, seriously)

Vehicle, and a few cans of gas.

Now I have no idea how to refill the vehicle. The UI is not always that great in this game. So how do I refill the gas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refill vehicles in the tactical view only. Put the gas in the mercs hand. And use it on the vehicle. You get a special icon. (Which imho, looks a bit like a mouse with a cord, or a tampon).

And there is a [*bug*](http://www.ja-galaxy-forum.com/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=163592&page=2), you need to be more than 2 squares away from the vehicle you are trying to refill.

The

> Hummer

Can be refilled at the place you buy it for free. But it does not always have gas available.